# this error "Default activity not found"

Tags: android, android-studio

Am a newbie in android studio,
I can't figure out how to stop this error even looking into other posts. I don't understand how to add activity in the manifest. Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.drpg.dungeonkeys"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="Beta.4.44" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".DungeonKey"
            android:label="@string/dungeon_key"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.view.im" android:resource="@xml/method"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>            
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to declare launcher Activity to your manifests

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

declare your activity as the launcher which you want to start first.

Answer (score 1):

Your manifest need to look something like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="[YOUR_PACKAGE]">

    <!-- Differents permissions you need -->

    <application
    ... >
        <!-- Here default activity -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Other activity declarations -->
        <activity
            android:name=".OtherActivity" />

        <!-- If you have some services, write them here -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: So the `<service>` in the manifest is not required? imported from eclipse ADT

Comment: Of course if you have services, put them. Pls look edited answer. Here in your first post, you just missed to add <activity> with the intent filter that specifiy it's the first activity of your app to launch.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `<activity>` tag in your manifest file.

Simplest version is :

```
<activity
     android:name="com.drpg.dungeonkeys.ActivityName"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Check out this official tutorial : 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Here you have detailed info about `<activity>` tag : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: `.ActivityName` ??

Comment: This is name of the Activity you want to declare. Check provided links.

Comment: `android:name="com.drpg.dungeonkeys.DungeonKey`" !! error

Comment: Quite obvious : DungeonKey isn't class that extends Activity class (it extends Service class I guess). Past code of this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)'s page for the app manifest, you will see that you need to declare all your activities there. The following code comes **directly from that page**, I removed some of it to shorten the answer.

```
<manifest>

    <application>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to add activities in the Manifest file.

the intent filter is not a necessary tag for all activities, it is optional.

Add Activity in application tag in your manifest:

```
<!-- Main Activity-->
    <activity android:name="YourActivityName" >
        <intent-filter>
      <!-- MAIN represents that it is the Main Activity-->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <!-- Launcher Denotes that it will be the first launching activity-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <!--Add Other activities like this-->
    <activity android:name="YourActivityName2" >
 <!--Default Intent Filter-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <!--OR Other activities like this And  intent filter is not necessary in other activites-->
    <activity android:name="YourActivityName3" >
    </activity>
 <!--OR Add Other activities like this-->
    <activity android:name="YourActivityName4" />
```